# How to use JSONata with CARML?

Tags: java, rdf, jsonpath, jsonata, rml-rdf

May I ask if anyone tried to use **JSONata4Java** in **CARML** (https://github.com/carml/carml)?

It needs to implement `getSourceIterator()` and `getExpressionEvaluatorFactory()`, which are in **LogicalSourceResolver** interface at **com.taxonic.carml.logical_source_resolver** package.

Any thoughts/directions?

Comment: What have you tried till so far to implment following methods?

Comment: For the first one, I tried to find a JSONata iterator like the one in Jayway, but there is nothing I can found. Also, not sure if the Jayway iterator will work instead (hacky and don't guarantee the output). For the second one, there is no clear expression elevator factory.